# Will this Free the data correctly?

Tags: c++, memory, iterator, memory-leaks, allocation

I just want to know if this will correctly free the data.

Pseudo Code:

```
std::map<std::string, ClassPointer*>::iterator tempIterator;

    for(tempIterator = directory.begin(); tempIterator < directory.end; 
        tempIterator++)
        delete &tempIterator;
```

Comment: I don't think you need the & because the iterator is already a pointer to the address location. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: This is something you could verify by using valgrind.  If you run your C++ code inside the memcheck app, it should be able to tell you if all of the memory was properly freed.

Comment: @Ben and OP it should be `delete *tempIterator`.

Comment: @SethCarnegie the container is map which should be `delete tempIterator->second` ?

Comment: @SethCarnegie I tried that and it gave be an error. &tempIterator never gave me an error. Anyways I think I solved the answer by putting delete tempIterator->second.

Comment: @billz yep, missed that it was a `map`.

Answer (score 4):

As directory stores raw pointer, it's your responsibility to delete these pointers when necessary.

```
std::map<std::string, ClassPointer*>::iterator tempIterator;

for(tempIterator = directory.begin(); tempIterator < directory.end(); 
    tempIterator++)
{
    delete tempIterator->second;
}
```

Always, better solution is to use smart pointer in STL containers:

```
 std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<ClassPointer>> directory;
```

Answer (score 2):

If `ClassPointer*` is allocated with `new[]`, this piece of code may not work properly. Using smart pointers instead is a better idea.

And FYI, it should be

```
for (auto tempIterator = directory.begin(); tempIterator != directory.end(); 
    ++tempIterator)
```

Comment: I'm really in doubt that `ClassPointer*` was allocated by `new[]`, cuz in that way (storing just a pointer in the map) he lose a size of array, so raw pointer become useless... there is no way to iterate over that array...

Comment: @zaufi There is situations that objects are allocated by `new[]` and inserted into the `map`, though it's not the best practice.

Answer (score 1):

the correct way is:

```
for (
    std::map<std::string, ClassPointer*>::iterator it = directory.begin()
  , last = directory.end()     // avoid call to end() every time
  ; it != last                 // use operator != (NOT operator <)
  ; ++it                       // prefer prefix increment for iterators!
  ) delete it->second;         // iterator points to std::pair actually!
```

or C++11 way:

```
for (auto& item : directory) delete item.second;
```

and BTW, this will only free a class pointer, not a map element! (so pointer in the map became invalid, but item remains in the map)

Comment: The advice about not calling end() every time is antiquated. All standard libraries cash this value. If it does not change the cost of getting it is constant (and optimized away by in-lining). This is a premature optamization let the compiler work on this kind of optimization you work on algorithms.

Comment: @LokiAstari Can you give me a 100% guarntee about "All standard libraries cash this value"?? Is 'ALL' include all past and future versions of all compilers/libs? :) (just a brief look into STL of gcc 4.7.2 tells me that you are wrong)

Standard have no such guarantee! So it is why **better** to show this explicitly (consider this as a coding style!). Of cause modern C++ compilers will (probably) move that call out of `for` body, but explicit using `last` just helps 'em to avoid to do that job... so I consider this feature mostly like a good practice (coding style) not as an optimization...

Comment: @zuufi: Does it matter it they do or don't? No. The optimization here makes the code harder to read. Harder to maintain (as a change in the body can make it wrong). Hard to write. This is also lots of easy optimizations for the compiler here. So no redeaming features for using it.

Comment: @LokiAstari ... I consider this as a good practice, cuz calling `end()` is just a simplest case. Here is a plenty cases, especially when you use iterator adaptors (like `std::make_move_iterator`, or smth from boost::iterator library, like `transform_iterator`) it **always** better to explicitly introduce `last` variable in scope of `for`... it makes code **readable and maintainable**

Comment: I am not wrong (read my statement more carefully). No; this **is** bad practice. It was a practice that people attempted to encouraged about a decade ago. It never caught on in the mainstream and I would consider it non idiomatic C++ thus harder to read/write and maintain. Check SO how many other places do you see this.

Comment: what are you talking about compiler optimizatoins and `for` loops??? check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433300
--
SO, is a full of stuents/noobs, who learn C++ -- are you seriously expected to find here a complex enough (mainstream) code snippets?
--
anyway, I'll leave you with your (particular) opinion... and stay w/ mine, tested in vast of projects...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23075/discussion-between-zaufi-and-loki-astari)

Comment: Your surprised that strlen() an O(n) function is slower than calling size() an O(1) function. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-invariant_code_motion as the call to end(). Yes SO has newcomers but also lots of experts. find **any** expert that uses your technique. They don't its bad practice. It has **NO benefits** and the disadvantages are big in readability/writ-ability and maintainability.