# character array and printf makes program slow

Tags: c++

(Um,My english is not well)   :)

My friend is learning C++ now,and he find a problem that I can't explain why.

The First Code ,it runs more than 2000MS

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio> 
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int ans[2000000];
char a[2000000];

int main()
{
    scanf("%s\n",a);
    int l=1,r=strlen(a);
    for (int i=0;i<strlen(a);i++) 
        if (a[i]=='l')
            ans[r--] = i+1;
        else
            ans[l++] = i+1;
    for (int i=1;i<=strlen(a);i++)
        printf("%d\n",ans[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

The Second Code,it runs 465MS

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int ans[2000000];
char a[2000000];
int size;

int main()
{
    scanf("%s",a);
    int l=1,r=strlen(a);
    size = r;
    for (int i=0;i<strlen(a);i++) 
        if (a[i]=='l') ans[r--]=i+1;else ans[l++]=i+1;
    for (int i=1;i<=size;i++)
        printf("%d\n",ans[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

The Third Code,it runs more than 2000MS

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int ans[2000000];
char a[2000000];
int size;

int main()
{
    scanf("%s",a);
    int l=1,r=strlen(a);
    size = r;
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++) 
        if (a[i]=='l') ans[r--]=i+1;else ans[l++]=i+1;
    for (int i=1;i<=strlen(a);i++)
        printf("%d\n",ans[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

The Last Code ,it runs 515MS

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int ans[2000000];
string a;

int main()
{
cin >>a;
    int l=1,r=a.size();
    for (int i=0;i<a.size();i++) 
        if (a[i]=='l') ans[r--]=i+1;else ans[l++]=i+1;
    for (int i=1;i<=a.size();i++)
        printf("%d\n",ans[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

When input string size is 10^5

So , the reason is about second for loop.

And my question is why "strlen" function and print in for loop will make the code so slow?

Comment: You're wondering why doing `strlen` over 2MB, two million times, takes a second or two?

Comment: You seem to want the 1-based indices of 'l' characters in `a` populated in the highest indices in `ans`, with non-`l` characters in the lower indices.  But, `ans[r--]` is one too far to `ans` - you'll end up with a presumably-unwanted `0` value in the middle of `ans`.  If this is unwanted, replace `ans[r--]` with `ans[--r]`.  As others have said, you only need `const size_t len = strlen(a);` above your loops, then replace all the other `strlen(a)` with `len`.

Comment: Did you run all the programs multiple times (dozens, at least) and take the average to ensure that the timings are reasonably reliable?

Comment: @molbdnilo  yes，I submit the program to OnlineJudge(Codeforces)  many times,it uses g++ 4.7.2 to judge my program.

Comment: @volz.kz.g That's not a very reliable timing method. You should run the programs on your own machine and use the same input for all of them. An input string dominated by 'l' might be slower than one with few 'l's (due to the way you're accessing `ans`) or vice versa (due to branch prediction), and I/O time will vary with the input. You can't draw any conclusions unless you control the input.

Answer (score 0):

The `strlen` function has to be executed each time through the loop when you have it in the loop.  That's an extra function call, and it has to run through the full string to find it's length.

Caching the length in `size`, means that none of that has to be redone every time through the loop.

So, there is no error.  This is expected behavior.

Comment: Um，But when I change the first for-loop's strlen function to size ,it runs fast.

Comment: That's because `size` is just a variable.  But `strlen` is a function.  So you have stored the result of `strlen()` in `size`.  `strlen(`) only gets called once.  When you don't use `size` to store the result, `strlen()` gets called every time through the loop.  Saving the result of a function in a variable is a great way to speed thing up, if you know that the result is not going to change!

Comment: Sorry，my description was wrong. It should be when I only change the second for-loop's strlen function to size,it runs fast.But when I only change the first for-loop's strlen function to size,it runs slow.

Comment: @volz.kz.g: You're trying to apply simplistic logic to draw a conclusion from the results you're seeing, but failing to consider a whole host of factors, such as caching, the writes into the array, and the fact that you're still dealing with _two million elements_.

Comment: My suggestion:  can you look at the assembly?  Or run a profiler?  This will reveal why optimizing the different loops is getting you different results.  Finally, though you should not expect the loops to be optimizable to the same extent.  They are different.

Comment: I change the question description.Maybe it looks more  intuitive

Answer (score 0):

By writing `strlen` in the loop condition — a loop with *two million* iterations — you are scanning through a two-megabyte string two million times. Of course that's going to take some time!

That delay goes away when you pre-calculate the string length just once.

Also, you will probably find that streaming 2MB of text to the console is going to be noticeably "slow" in any case.

Comment: Thank you ,but that's not what I want to know.And I have test the time when I only make first for-loop have strlen ,it runs fast